# How to align depth and color in Arcore?

Tags: android, arcore

I'm writing a small Android app for my P30Pro in which I want to find an object in the color image (face, visual marker, ...) and then get its relative position by using the dense depth image from the Time-of-Flight camera. To simultaneously track the camera, I run ArCore and use a SharedSession to access the color image as well as the depth image via frame.acquireDepthImage(). (Both works well, I get a high resolution color image and a 120x160 depth image)

For the color image, I get the intrinsic calibration via camera.getImageIntrinsics, so I can map between a pixel and the corresponding ray.
I however found no corresponding function for the depth camera, so that I can't create a pointcloud from the depth image or get the corresponding depth for a pixel in the color image.

So: "How can I find the corresponding 3D Point for a given pixel in the color image by using the dense depth image?"

Comment: Any reply on this... I found same the arcore color resolution is 640 x 480 and depth image output is 640 x 360  in Samsung Galaxy S 20 + .. I probably believe it should be cropping but it might be compressing the image from 480 to 360 also. Any reply's are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I previously worked on a project that used P20 Pro's dense depth maps, and I found they were already aligned with the high resolution color image, even though they were much smaller resolution.

In other words, you should just upsample the depth map so it matches the color image's resolution. Once you do that, you should find that the interpolated depth value at `(r,c)` in the upsampled depth image corresponds to the pixel at `(r,c)` in the color image.